# Function that returns object: how to avoid casting AND option strict off? (VB.Net)

Tags: vb.net, object, casting

I have a function called `GetField` that grabs a value from a specified `DataTable` column/row. The object returned depends on the type of the value grabbed (eg. Integer/String/Boolean/Date, etc). For this reason, the function returns `Object`. It was pretty convenient when I had `Option Strict Off` since I could use the same function whenever I wanted to grab a field and have it automatically converted to the right type implicitly. The problem is that when using `GetField` with `Option Strict On`, it is necessary to cast every usage, which clutters up code considerably since this function is used all the time.

Is `Option Strict Off` reasonable to use in this case, or is there a more elegant solution to this problem?

Comment: IMO, a more elegant solution would be to write a generic function that returns the correct type.  `Option Strict Off` is lazy, IMO.

Comment: Why don't you use the available [`Field(Of T)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360891(v=vs.110).aspx) extension method?

Comment: There is some irony here, this used to work.  The addition of dynamic programming support to .NET 4.0 made VB.NET *less* dynamic.  You can leverage a Partial Class to put this code in another source code file that has Option Strict Off at the top.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want to have to cast each time, you will need to set `Option Strict Off`.  Personally, I'd say that's the wrong way to go, though.  There are times when shutting it off makes sense, but doing it just to save yourself some extra typing is a poor excuse.

The only shortcut I can offer is to either make separate `GetField` methods for each type (e.g. `GetFieldBoolean`, `GetFieldString`), or you can make it generic, like this:

```
Public Function GetField() As Object
    ' Do normal logic ...
End Function

Public Function GetField(Of T)() As T
    Return DirectCast(GetField(), T)
End Function
```

Then, instead of having to call `CType` or `DirectCast` each time, you can just call it like this:

```
Dim value As Boolean = GetField(Of Boolean)()
```

As Tim, mentioned, though, since .NET Framework 3.5, the `DataRow` class already has a [`Field(Of T)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarowextensions.field%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) extension method which does exactly that.  So in this particular case, it seems like you might be reinventing the proverbial wheel.

Comment: OP is trying to get a field of a `DataRow` strongly typed. Isn't that exactly what [`Field(Of T)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360891(v=vs.110).aspx) does?

Comment: @TimSchmelter, Yes, I just added that to my answer :)  good point.